# Delete post: 2 wp_redirect if pages are different

Tags: page-template, wp-redirect, customization

My website allows users to publish and manage posts from frontend. I've created a kind of account section where they have all their posts published which they can edit and delete. They can even delete posts through the **post page (single.php)**. So 2 cases:

- My account page (listing all posts): quick actions -> delete post. **It works fine**, not being necessary a redirect. The page refresh and post is gone.
- The internal post page (single.php): actions -> delete. In this case I should redirect my people to their account page or wherever else because they get a not_found page after the action. **This is my problem**.

I could specify a `wp_redirect(get_permalink(my_account_page_id))` during the action but my functions is not in-page and it's called through `do_action` by my `functions.php`. So I should check every time if they are into their account or  in the internal post page (`single.php`).
I've even tried using `$pagenow` but without success.

My action in **functions.php** call a modal and looks like:

```
add_action('delete_post', 'delete_p_function');
    function delete_p_function($pid) { 
        global $wpdb; $pagenow;
        $delete = 'delete_'.$pid;
        if(isset($_POST[$delete]))
        {
            wp_delete_post($pid);
            if($pagenow == 'single.php'):
                wp_redirect(get_permalink(my_account_page_id));
            endif;
        } ?>
        <div id="delete-<?php echo $pid?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <form method="post" class="top-15 text-center">
                        <input type="submit" name="delete_<?php echo $pid?>" class="submit_red" value="<?php _e("Delete",'KleeiaDev'); ?>" style="width:100%; text-align:center"/>
                </form>
           </div>
        </div>

    <?php }
```

Of course if is not `single.php` there is no `action` in `<form>` so the page will be refreshed. So it's fine for the listing page.
But how can i check if is in page single.php?

PS. I've even tried `is_page_template()` without success.

Comment: Somebody can give me a direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this native function will help you:

```
 if ( is_single() ) {
     //do stuff
 }
```

You will find [more information](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) in the WP developers section.
It works for any post type, except attachments and pages.

Comment: I've tried and debug says 'Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...'. How can I manage this problem? Basically the redirect does not take place.

Comment: Can you copy here all the warning message?

Comment: I've actually solved and thank you for your support!